# Python the While loop

Tags: python

Help! I wrote a simple code that asks the user for a number from 1 to 100, this number is different every time. The problem is that the operation does not end until the number randomly drops out during randomization.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufgRU.png)

I tried to fix it but it didn't work out

Comment: "I wrote a simple code that asks the user for a number from 1 to 100, this number is different every time" - uh, no, that's not what that code is doing. That code "guesses" 1, then randomly generates numbers *to* guess until a guess of 1 happens to be correct.

Comment: Could you share the code you have written? We cannot help you if you don't post your code

Comment: The `else:` block of a loop is executed if the loop ends normally instead of from `break`. Your loop doesn't have any `break` statements, so it will always execute the `else:` block. If you don't want that, you should use `break` instead of using the `running` variable to control the loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have defined a constant 'guess' with the value '1'.

Then you start looping. Every iteration you generate a pseudo-random number from 1 to 100 and save it into the 'number' variable.

Then you do a check: if the generated number is equal to your constant - give a signal to stop your loop, else print a hint and continue.

So basically, the code does what you've called a 'problem', and this is not a problem, but an expected behavior:

> the operation does not end until the number randomly drops out during randomization

If you want the user to guess the number, you have to generate a random number in line 2 of your code, and use an [**input()**](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) function in line 5.

So every iteration the user will be asked for a number, which will be compared with the pre-generated pseudo-random number.